# Web se ralentiza debido a table con miles de registros

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Buenas tardes, me encuentro realizando una biblioteca con PHP, MySQL y JS para un familiar. Cuando me lo pidió, me dijo que no quería ver los resultados paginados, sino todos en la misma página. El problema viene cuano me carga miles de registros en una **table**, ya que se ralentizan las funciones de Javascript, como una dedicada a arrastrar columnas a través del th, haciendo muy poco usable la aplicación.
¿Algún consejo o algo para poder solucionar este problema?

El código de dicha función es obtenido de aquí: https://akottr.github.io/dragtable/

Aquí el código PHP que rellena la tabla.

```
<?php
//Se realiza un include con el script necesario para la conexión a la  BBDD y las funciones
include "../funciones.php";
include "../conexion.php";
//Consulta SQL necesaria para la información a a mostrar
$sql = "SELECT libros.nref, libros.portada, libros.titulo,libros.isbn,libros.edicion,libros.encuadernacion,libros.coleccion,libros.idioma,libros.puntuacion,libros.comentario,libros.leido,libros.precio,DATE_FORMAT(libros.anyocompra, '%d-%m-%Y') as fechacompra,DATE_FORMAT(libros.fechapublicacion, '%d-%m-%Y') as fechapublicacion,libros.fechaintroduccion, autores.anombre, editoriales.enombre, g.gnombre,sg.gnombre as subgenero, localizaciones.lnombre, lugarcompra.lcnombre from libros
          left JOIN autores on libros.autor = autores.aid 
          left JOIN editoriales on libros.editorial = editoriales.eid
          left JOIN generos as g on libros.genero = g.gid 
          left JOIN generos as sg on libros.subgenero = sg.gid 
          left JOIN localizaciones on libros.localizacion = localizaciones.lid
          left JOIN lugarcompra on libros.lugarcompra = lugarcompra.lcid order by nref asc";
$resultado = $con->query($sql);
if ($resultado->num_rows == 0){
  echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('La tabla se encuentra vacía')";
  echo "</script>";
    exit;
}
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='fichalibros.php?nref=$fila[nref]'>".$fila["nref"]."</td></a>
    <td>".$fila["titulo"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["isbn"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["anombre"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["enombre"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["gnombre"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["subgenero"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["edicion"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["lnombre"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["encuadernacion"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["coleccion"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["idioma"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["puntuacion"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["leido"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["precio"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["lcnombre"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["fechacompra"]."</td>
    <td>".$fila["fechapublicacion"]."</td>
    <td><form method=post action='../delete.php'><button class='btn btn-danger' type='Submit' name='borrado' value='$fila[nref]''>Borrar</button><input type='hidden' name='tabla' value='libros'></td></form>
    <td><form method='post' action='updatelibros.php'><button class='btn btn-primary' type='Submit' name='update' value='$fila[nref]'>Actualizar</button></form></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tbody></table>";
// Liberar resultados
$resultado->free();
// Cerrar la conexión
$con->close();
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Mario, no puedo ponerlo como respuesta pero si como consejo, te recomendaría usar Datatables ahí puedes poner cuantos registros tu quieras y hacerlos por pagina ya que cargando la DB completa en una pagina claramente tendrá menor usabilidad y mayor tiempo de carga, Datatables trae un buscador también el que puede usar para ubicar datos necesarios

Comment: No me queda claro como se usa el resultado. Si bajar todos los datos complica el javascript la opción es no bajar todo sino solo lo necesario y ver que puede bajarse en una seguna instancia con ajax por ejemplo para que la experiencia del usuario no se vea tan afectada. @Mario Datatables está bueno pero también se pone pesado con muchos registros cuando querés filtrar por ejemplo.

Comment: Al final he optado por crear una paginación, el mal rendimiento no creo que se deba al código, sino de la carga que recibe el navegador al cargar tanto dato.